# Default translation file in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, xslt

How can I have a general translation file including some common words for using in multiple bundle located in same namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are in the same app you can resort to the `app/Resources/translations` folder. This location, in addition, overrides the translation messages of any bundles.

> Symfony looks for message files (i.e. translations) in the following
>   locations:
>
> - the app/Resources/translations directory;
> - the app/Resources//translations directory;
> - the Resources/translations/ directory    inside of any bundle.
>
> The locations are listed here with the highest priority first. That
>   is, you can override the translation messages of a bundle in any of
>   the top 2 directories.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations